# Checking for collision in SWIFT

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, xcode6, collision-detection, bitmask

I have two objects that I want to collide: ball and centerBlock.
I created physics bodies for each and wrote the following:

```
ball.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = BodyType.ballCategory.toRaw()
ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: ball.size.height / 2)
ball.physicsBody!.dynamic = false
ball.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = BodyType.ballCategory.toRaw() | BodyType.centerBlockCategory.toRaw()
ball.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.centerBlockCategory.toRaw()

centerBlock.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = BodyType.centerBlockCategory.toRaw()
centerBlock.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: centerBlock.size)
centerBlock.physicsBody!.dynamic = false
```

Now I am not sure what to write in the didBeginContact method to check if the two objects collided. I am not very experienced with spritekit or swift so i currently have nothing written in this method. I want to detect when the two collide because that is supposed to end the game. Thanks!

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Physics/Physics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH6-SW14

Comment: Go to RayWenderlich.com and follow the beginner tutorial.  It has every bit of code you need.

Comment: No. Actually I already watched those videos and it doesn't work.